# Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in /home/cabox/workspace/writing/login.php on line 6

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, fatal-error

This is my code:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", '060419');
mysqli_select_db($conn, "lol");
$login ="SELECT * FROM username";
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,$login);
$pw = "mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)";
$username = $pw["username"];
$id = $pw["id"]
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
  if($_POST["username"] == $username){
    echo '<a href="http://php-
 noamboy2006504805.codeanyapp.com/writing/realindex.php?user='.$id.'">로그인 
성공
</a>';
  }else{
    echo '로그인 실패<a href="http://php-
noamboy2006504805.codeanyapp.com/writing/index.php">다시 시도</a>';
  }
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I keep getting this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted
>   to string in /home/cabox/workspace/writing/login.php on line 6

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pw = "mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)";
$username = $pw["username"];
```

Problem is here, maybe you meant to do:

```
 $pw = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
 $username = $pw["username"];
```

Because right now, $pw is a string that contains "mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)", not an array

Comment: how do i do it?

Comment: There should be a tick next to the arrows on the left side of this answer, just press that.

Answer (score 1):

You have added double quotes to your line `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, which is making it string:

```
$pw = "mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)";
```

Change it to this:

```
$pw = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
```